# How to check credentials against django tastypie webservice

Tags: django, tastypie

Hi I am building a web service using HttpBasicAuth for authentication on top of Django authentication. Using tastypie this works flawlessly with minimal configuration. However I'm trying to figure out the best way to simply check the credentials with the service before making any actual calls to my resources for data. Is there some best practice way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I eventually solved it.

```
class LoginResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
    allowed_methods = ['get']
    resource_name = 'login'
    include_resource_uri = False
    object_class = User
    authentication = BasicAuthentication()
    authorization = DjangoAuthorization()

def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    return [bundle.request.user]
```

Still interested in hearing what others have to say on this, maybe there is still a better way ?

Comment: Using DjangoAuthorization() is the key.
I can't really understand what you're trying to do with your obj_get_list() though.  Usually you just want to use a Django login page, see the Django docs on how to build one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/

Comment: Its a webservice.. There is no page.

Comment: Why do you attempt to login? `BasicAuthentication` passes all the auth info with every request, so basically it's not required unless you are doing some stuff with sessions.